Partial Least Squares model returning negative values for curve or spline like output
I have a dataset which measures the different altitude of a basketball thrown at 4 intervals, 1 second, 2 seconds, 3 seconds, 4 seconds. The features are weight, height, years in sports participation. I'm using partial least squares to predict the 4 second intervals as targets.
In general the model estimates well, as expected it exhibits a curve shape where the highest value is the max altitude and usually occurring at the 2 second and then tapers off. However when simulating random values for the x's there are times where the model will return negative values for the targets. Sometimes just one time interval and other time all four. The desired model output is to never have a value below 0 (that's not physically possible as a ball cannot go into the ground!) and produce a smooth like spline output in a curvature shape. How does one solve this where the model will never output a negative value in this use-case?

positive values
I imagine you have video of several athletes vertically tossing basketballs into the air.
From which we've made four Altitude AGL (above ground level) measurements.

The features are weight, height, years in sports participation.


desired model output is to never have a value below 0 (that's not physically possible as a ball cannot go into the ground!)

I reject the "never below 0!" requirement.
Imagine an athlete standing near the edge of a cliff,
who tosses a ball approximately vertically,
such that it goes over the cliff and descends into the void.
Computing negative altitudes would make perfect sense in this context.
physics model
Let us simplify the situation.
Assume the gymnasium being studied is in perfect vacuum.
Then we obtain a very straightforward
physics model,
with vertical acceleration $g$ set by the local gravity field.
The $y$ coordinate at time $t$ will be
$v_0t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$.
And negative altitudes, using the "cliff" interpretation, are entirely sensible.
We could adopt a more sophisticated physics model in
STP
conditions, where velocity induces a drag component on acceleration,
but it sounds like you haven't gone there, which is fine.
Knowing an athlete's height and weight are useful,
they can yield e.g. an informative statistic like
BMI.
But the height offset ($y_0$) is perhaps inconvenient
for your modeling efforts.
You may find it helpful to subtract it from all altitudes,
so we have a basketball being launched vertically from the origin.
What knowing certain characteristics of the athlete will really help
you with is predicting initial $v_0$ velocity.
And then the kinematics equations tie that to your observed altitudes.
post-processing
Your "never have a value below 0" requirement suggests
you'd prefer to deal with a non-linear $\max(0, y)$, rather than a simple $y$ prediction.
Or perhaps your video and altitude observations reveal
bouncing
behavior after striking the floor?
In which case you may want a more complex model
that accounts for heat energy loss due to friction.
If you post-process observed values,
tell your model about that
so it can respond appropriately.

Hi J_H, thank you for your time to answer my question. The above is just an example of the issue of never returning a non-positive estimate I am having. The ball and altitude in different times is an illustration where using a PLS or other multivariate target variables could return a non-positive for one, or all targets that is expected to behave in a curve or spline like smooth output. I have seen recommendations of using log transform, possison regression, ridge, etc, but just wondering if this is something that can be done innately within PLS method.

The way that a falling basketball interacts with a gymnasium floor is clearly not behaving with a curve or spline-like smooth output. You chose to ask an XY problem, rather than revealing details of your input dataset, implemented code, results, nor even citing a reference. Recommend you click Accept on the answer and then ask a new question describing what you really care about.
